# Remap keys in replace mode in vim

Tags: vim

I'm attempting to swap my semicolon and colon keys.

I use this function

```
func! FUNC_Remap(lhs, rhs)
    " Function which remaps keys in all modes
    "
    ":echom 'inoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    "http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)
    "  CHAR MODE    ~
    " <Space>   Normal, Visual, Select and Operator-pending
    "n  Normal
    "v  Visual and Select
    "s  Select
    "x  Visual
    "o  Operator-pending
    "!  Insert and Command-line
    "i  Insert
    "l  ":lmap" mappings for Insert, Command-line and Lang-Arg
    "c  Command-line
    "--------------
    " Normal Mode
    :exec 'noremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Visual and Select Mode
    :exec 'vnoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Display select mode map
    :exec 'snoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Display visual mode maps
    :exec 'xnoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Operator Pending Mode
    :exec 'onoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Insert and Replace Mode
    :exec 'inoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Language Mode
    :exec 'lnoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
    " Command Line Mode
    :exec 'cnoremap '.a:lhs.' '.a:rhs
endfu
command! -nargs=* CMDREMAP call FUNC_Remap(<f-args>)

func! FUNC_Swap(lhs, rhs)
    :call FUNC_Remap(a:lhs, a:rhs)
    :call FUNC_Remap(a:rhs, a:lhs)
endfu
command! -nargs=* CMDSWAP call FUNC_Swap(<f-args>)    

:CMDSWAP : ;
```

which works in all instances but replace mode.

Reading the documentation it says that inoremap should cover replace mode but when I type r;  in normal mode I replace the current character with a semicolon instead of the colon which it should have been mapped to. Its quite annoying when everywhere else the mapping works.

How do I get key remapping to to work in Replace Mode?

Comment: `r` doesn't enter replace mode. If you want `r;` to replace the character under the cursor with a `:`, do `nnoremap r; r:`.

Comment: Awesome, I wish there was a more elegant way to remap that, but I can definitely work with this.

Comment: `nnoremap r; r:` is beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

*Replace mode* is the variant of insert mode that replaces the existing characters with the typed text. The single-character replacement done with `r` is not *replace mode*, nor is it a special mode; therefore, the `:map` commands don't apply there. A nice trick is to remap the entire command + char combination:

```
nnoremap r; r:
nnoremap r: r;
```

Alternatively, you can use `:lmap`; cp. `:help r`:

> ```
>       |:lmap| mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command
>       in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off
> ```

Comment: Bummer! As a Googler, I was actually hoping to get the answer to the real question of remapping in `REPLACE` mode (not `r`).